# How do I create components that can take positional children as arguments (Dart)?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I am looking for resources on how to make webcomponents that can take positional children arguments. Something like:

```dart
<x-editable-component>
  <span>{{value}}</span> // this could be any uneditable element
  <textarea>{{value}}</textarea> //could be any editable element
</x-editable-component>
```

The above element would display a span when in editable == false, and a textarea when editable == true. editable is a globally watched static variable.

I think it might be possible to get this sort of composing behavior with inheritance. However, I was wondering if it might be possible to do this in the composable fashion mentioned above. Where the component (x-editable-component) simply expects two children, one child it will display when editable, the other child it will display when uneditable.

To be clear, I want the flexibility of writing any two children as the children of x-editable-component, so maybe somewhere further down I have a x-editable component written as such.

```dart
<x-editable-component>
  <div>{{value}}</div> // this could be any uneditable element
  <input>{{value}}</input> //could be any editable element
</x-editable-component>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a great use for the `<content>` tag.

```dart
<element name="my-editable-component">
  <template>
    <div style="display: {{editing ? 'block' : 'none'}}">
      <content select=".editing"></content>
    </div>
    <div style="display: {{editing ? 'none' : 'block'}}">
      <content select=".normal"></content>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
    class MyEditableComponent extends WebComponent {
      bool editing = false;
      // ...
    }
  </script>
</element>
```

Here I'm using classes, but you can come up with whatever protocol you'd like. `<content select="">` can use most CSS selectors.

This would be used like:

```dart
<my-editable-component>
  <div class="normal">{{value}}</div>
  <input class="editing">{{value}}</input>
</my-editable-component>
```

More information about "content" can be found on the [web-ui article](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#composition) or you can see the example in the [shadowdom spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/shadow/index.html#shadow-dom-example).

Please note: I'm using `display: none` instead of `<template if>` to workaround https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/228

Comment: Using your code as a template, I was able to get my own code working. Really interesting this <content> tag thing. On one hand it sort of breaks the wysiwyg nature of declarative views. On the other, it allows you to abstract (hide) unnecessary details. I feel that it was appropriate in this case, but it requires some consideration as you are breaking the declarative mapping from your own code to the structure of the dom.